# Only show part of template if there exists at least one child-object

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a model like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  downloads: DS.hasMany('download')
});

export default Post;
```

and would like to show the downloads-section only when there is at least 1 or more downloads in the post.

I tried introducing a computed property in the Controller but can't access the model from there.

What else can I do?

EDIT: Here's the controller showing you what I was trying to do:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  hasDownloads: function(){
    console.log(this.get('downloads')) // <- undefined
    return true
  }.property('model'),

})
```

EDIT2: The Object-controller above has no route since it's rendered using `{{render "post"}}. This is an example-template.

```
<ul class="posts">
  {{#with model as post}}
  {{render "post"}}
  {{/with}}
</ul>
```

That would be its route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('post', params).then(function(posts) {
      return posts.get('firstObject');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean you cannot access your model from your controller? Can you show the code for what you were trying to do?

Comment: all attributes of the post are `undefined` in the controller. I added the relevant code.

Comment: Verify that `firstObject` exists as you expect.

Comment: The whole post is rendered in my template. It's just that I don't know how to access the downloads Object-Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly access the property on your controller using `model.downloads`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  hasDownloads: function(){
    console.log(this.get('model.downloads'))
    return true
  }.property('model.@each'),
})
```

Depending upon which version of Ember you are using, the proxying behavior of the controller will no longer work. Also, change the property so that it is updated when downloads are added and removed.

Comment: the `log` command adds `null` to the log. I'm using Ember 1.10

Comment: What does your route look like? Have you verified that data is available to the application using the Ember Inspector?

Comment: There is no route (which I forgot up until now, sorry). It's a central template & controller called post I use all over the place like this:
`  {{#with model as post}}
  {{render "post"}}
  {{/with}}`
The post-template uses what is inside `post`
Is it still possible to use that data in the controller of post?

Comment: Please post the code around how you are populating the data that you are passing in within your route, how you are passing in data and how you are using the template.

Comment: I added an example-route and template to the top post.

Comment: I was able to access the model by providing it as a second parameter to the render-handlebars helper {{render "post" model}}